# .gitignore is not ignoring a file on a fresh repository. Is there more to the file cache than the .git directory?

Tags: git

I’m trying to use git in addition to mercurial and have used my .hgignore file as a starting point.

My `.gitignore file` contains the line:

> ./homeautomation/homeassistant/home-assistant_v2.db

I have made sure that there is no `.git` directory, and then I initialized the repo and did an add and commit.  I used the ignore errors option because some of these files are in use.

```
wb@docker:~/stacks$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/wb/stacks/.git/

wb@docker:~/stacks$ git add . --ignore-errors

error: open("homeautomation/homeassistant/.storage/auth"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file homeautomation/homeassistant/.storage/auth
error: open("network/pihole/pihole/list.0.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file network/pihole/pihole/list.0.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains
error: open("network/pihole/pihole/list.1.mirror1.malwaredomains.com.domains"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file network/pihole/pihole/list.1.mirror1.malwaredomains.com.domains
error: open("network/pihole/pihole/list.3.zeustracker.abuse.ch.domains"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file network/pihole/pihole/list.3.zeustracker.abuse.ch.domains
error: open("network/pihole/pihole/list.6.hosts-file.net.domains"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file network/pihole/pihole/list.6.hosts-file.net.domains

wb@docker:~/stacks$
```

When I do a commit, I see the following file being mentioned in the commit message:

> new file:   homeautomation/homeassistant/home-assistant_v2.db

This is despite the .gitignore file is specifically set to ignore this file.

I ran the following command:

> git ls-files ./homeautomation/homeassistant/home-assistant_v2.db

Which returned the file name.  After some reading, I then did the following.

```
wb@docker:~/stacks$ git rm --cached ./homeautomation/homeassistant/home-assistant_v2.db

error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
homeautomation/homeassistant/home-assistant_v2.db
(use -f to force removal)
wb@docker:~/stacks$
```

I then ran the command again with the “force” option and the file disappeared from the commit message.

My question is why am I having to use `git rm —cached` because the file should have never been added in the first place?  There was no `.git` directory when I started.

Comment: Don't use `./` at the front. The path name inside Git is `/homeautomation/homeas...` and Git will match this with or without a `/` at the front of the `.gitignore`, but not with `./` at the front.

Comment: I’ve tried this as well, with the same results.

Comment: My only other thought is that perhaps your `.gitignore` file can't be opened for some reason, or contains some invisible text (or is in UTF-16 or something equally dreadful) that causes the problem. Using `git check-ignore` can tell you which line of some `.gitignore` *ignores* an untracked file, but once the file is tracked, `git check-ignore` can't help, and it never says anything about a not-ignored file...

Answer (score 0):

Your `.gitignore` file has a `./` in it which it shouldn't have. Files are assumed to be relative to the the top level of the repository as long as the `.gitignore` file is as well. If you remove the `./`, then your file should be properly ignored.

Comment: It does in fact make a big difference. Git definitely won't ignore files that are listed with the `./`. There may be other reasons it's failing if you remove it, but if it's there, it definitely won't work.